# Apple WatchOS simulator - possible to simulate Always On mode (for complications)?

Tags: ios-simulator, watchos, watchos-simulator

I am looking for a way to simulate Always On mode (for testing complications with `getAlwaysOnTemplate`), and so far I wasn't successful.

Is there a way to make the simulator turn on Always On mode?